# Enable SSL in PHP built in server

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am developing an application using PHP **[slim](/questions/tagged/slim)** framework and using the **[aws-sdk](/questions/tagged/aws-sdk)** to upload images to AWS S3.

Is it possible to enable ssl in **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** [Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) or do I have to use **[xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp)**?